# How to correctly link C++ objects using GLFW functions in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors, glfw, undefined-reference

I've created a very simple program containing multiple files and I'm now trying to link the GLFW library to it. I've only added GLFW functions to the file main.cpp and only include the library there, and only compiling and executing this file using the command `g++ main.cpp -lglfw` goes fine.

Before I added this library, compiling and linking the entire program also went fine, but even though there are no GLFW functions used in the other files when I want to link everything together (`g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -lglfw main.o hello_world.o console.o`) I suddenly get the error 'undefined reference to' every GLFW function I used. (I got no error while compiling main.cpp: `g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -lglfw -c main.cpp`)

This is the file main.cpp:

```
#include "basis.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
// Open-GL
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
/// Setup:
/// sudo apt-get update
/// sudo apt-get install libglfw3
/// sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
/// Compile:
/// g++ main.cpp -lglfw

using namespace std;

void errorCallback(int error, const char* description) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

void test() {
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        cout << "Window creation failed!" << endl;
    }
    runConsole();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        cout << "GLFW initialization failed!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    test();

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, I do not know where the library is located on my machine. Also, the Linux machine is Virtual Box, and the source code is in a shared folder located on my host windows system, but this his never created problems with libraries before as I compile them on Linux.

Comment: If you have `pkg-config` installed you can use `$(pkg-config glfw3 --libs)` at the end of your link command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, while re-reading the question I thought of a new solution, and it worked :) The correct linker command is: `g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 main.o hello_world.o console.o -lglfw`